# What headers do I need to set to get in my Fetch Request?

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api, svelte

I'm trying to get a Fetch request in a Svelte component working. It works fine if I use curl and Postman. It looks like my headers may be wrong. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

This is the curl request:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:8000/parse --data 'locale=en_GB&text=Monday'
```

These are the headers set in Postman
[image]

And my code:

```
function handleClick() {
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/parse"
    fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: new URLSearchParams({
            locale: "en_GB",
            text: "Monday"
        })
    })
    .then(console.log("test"))
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
            response.json().then((data) => {
                console.log("data");
            })
        })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

Comment: What is happening with your fetch request? Do you get an error, not the right data?

Comment: Why `mode: 'no-cors',`?

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I was getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed error. That fixed it. 

I somehow managed to get it working but can't get seem to get the data from the response. I can see it the chrome response preview. How can I get access to it?

Answer (score 0):

The last 't' in Content-(t)ype should be capital

```
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
```